# Using QuerySet.update() versus ModelInstance.save() in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have been going back and forth about using `QuerySet.update()` versus `ModelInstance.save()`.

Obviously if there are lots of fields being changed, I'd use `save()`, but for updating a couple of fields, I think it's better to use `QuerySet.update()`.

The benefit of using `QuerySet.update()` is that you can have multiple threads running `update()` at the same time, on different fields of the same object, and you won't have race issues. The default `save()` method saves all the fields, so parallel `save()` from two threads will be problematic.

So then the issue is what if you have overloaded, custom `save()` methods. The best I can think of is to abstract whatever in the custom `save()` method into separate updater methods that actually uses `QuerySet.update()` to set a couple of fields in the model.

Has anyone used this pattern?

What's a bit irritating is that in Django Admin, even in editing in change list mode where you are editing just one field, the entire model is saved.

This basically means if someone has a change list open on his/her browser, while somewhere else in the system, a field gets updated, that updated value will be thrown away when this user saves changes from the change list.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing this? This sounds a lot like premature optimization.

Comment: I disagree on the premature optimization... I am trying to go for correctness. I want to make sure when there are parallel writes to the same object, each write updates a different fields, they don't overwrite each other's values. E.g. one write is changing a timestamp, while another is changing a status field. This occurs in my app, and if I use save() with both writes, I'd get the wrong result. This is correctness, not performance. When Django ORM has support for SELECT...FOR UPDATE, then transactions will solve this. I am surprised others don't run into this.

Comment: @OverClocked, django transactions can handle the issue of two writes on the same field

Answer (score 11):

The main reason for using `QuerySet.update()` is that you can update more than one object with just one database query, while every call to an object's `save` method will hit the database!

Another point worth mentioning is, that django's `pre_save` & `post_save` signals are only sent when you call an object's `save`-method, but not upon `QuerySet.update()`.

Coming to the conflict issues you describe, I think it would also be irritating if you hit 'save' and then you have to discover that afterwards some values are the same as when you changed them, but some that you left unchanged have changed?!? Of course it's up to you to modify the admin's `save_model` or the object's `save` method to the bahaviour you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you described about Django Admin is essentially about updating a model instance using an outdated copy. It is easy to fix by adding a version number to each model instance and increment the number on each update. Then in the `save` method of the model, just make sure what you are saving is not behind what is already in the database.

> I want to make sure when there are parallel writes to the same object, each write updates a different fields, they don't overwrite each other's values.

Depending on the application, this may or may not be a sensible thing. Saving a whole model even if only a single field is updated can often avoid breaking integrity of data. Thinking about the following example about travel itinerary of three-leg flight. Assume there is an instance of three fields representing three legs and three fields are `SF->LA`, `LA->DC`, `DC->NY`. Now if one update is to update the first two legs to `SF->SD`, `SD->DC`, and another update is to update the last two legs to `LA->SJ`, `SJ->NY`, and if you allow both to happen with `update` instead of saving the full model instance, you would come out with a broken itinerary of `SF->SD`, `LA->SJ`, `SJ->NY`.