# Django: save() vs update() to update the database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-models

I'm writing a Django app, and I need a function to update a field in the database.  Is there any reason to do one of these methods rather than the other?

```py
def save_db_field(name,field,value):
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(name=name)
    obj.field = value
    obj.save()

def update_db_field(name,field,value):
    MyModel.objects.get(name=name).update(field=value)
```

It seems like the second is better because it does it in one DB call instead of two.  Is there a reason why fetching, then updating is any better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using QuerySet.update() versus ModelInstance.save() in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519336/using-queryset-update-versus-modelinstance-save-in-django)

Comment: @sobolevn that question and answers are quite outdated since django was in version 1.0 or 1.1 or something like that. Those verisons are deprecated and not supported any more since a lot of changes happened during time.

Comment: @FallenAngel, yeah, a have seen the date first. But when I figured it out, I gave an answer.

Comment: Doesn't the call to `get` in the update example cause a lookup and remove any advantage you might have got from using update? IIUC then using `filter` there wouldn't cause an additional lookup?

Comment: I got this error when I tried update `AttributeError: 'TableName' object has no attribute 'update'` . `filter` seems to work but `get` is not

Comment: The `.update()` method only works with a QuerySet, which is the result of a `.filter()` method.  If you use `.get()` then you only get a single object, and you need to use `.save()`

Comment: Calling update() after get() on the object will throw an exception...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set component style from variable in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130705/set-component-style-from-variable-in-angular-2)

Comment: I also got **the error `AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'update'`** with `Person.objects.get(id=2).update(name="Tom")`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are several key differences.

`update` is used on a queryset, so it is possible to update multiple objects at once.

As [@FallenAngel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257972/fallenangel) pointed out, there are differences in how custom `save()` method triggers, but it is also important to keep in mind `signals` and `ModelManagers`. I have build a small testing app to show some valuable differencies. I am using Python 2.7.5, Django==1.7.7 and SQLite, note that the final SQLs may vary on different versions of Django and different database engines.

Ok, here's the example code.

`models.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

__author__ = 'sobolevn'

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        super_query = super(models.Manager, self).get_queryset()
        print('Manager is called', super_query)
        return super_query


class ExtraObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class TestModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    key = models.ForeignKey('ExtraObject')
    many = models.ManyToManyField('ExtraObject', related_name='extras')

    objects = CustomManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('save() is called.')
        super(TestModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        # Never do such things (access by foreing key) in real life,
        # because it hits the database.
        return u'{} {} {}'.format(self.name, self.key.name, self.many.count())


@receiver(pre_save, sender=TestModel)
@receiver(post_save, sender=TestModel)
def reicever(*args, **kwargs):
    print('signal dispatched')
```

`views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    if request and request.method == 'GET':

        from models import ExtraObject, TestModel

        # Create exmple data if table is empty:
        if TestModel.objects.count() == 0:
            for i in range(15):
                extra = ExtraObject.objects.create(name=str(i))
                test = TestModel.objects.create(key=extra, name='test_%d' % i)
                test.many.add(test)
                print test

        to_edit = TestModel.objects.get(id=1)
        to_edit.name = 'edited_test'
        to_edit.key = ExtraObject.objects.create(name='new_for')
        to_edit.save()

        new_key = ExtraObject.objects.create(name='new_for_update')
        to_update = TestModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(name='updated_name', key=new_key)
        # return any kind of HttpResponse
```

That resuled in these SQL queries:

```
# to_edit = TestModel.objects.get(id=1):
QUERY = u'SELECT "main_testmodel"."id", "main_testmodel"."name", "main_testmodel"."key_id" 
FROM "main_testmodel" 
WHERE "main_testmodel"."id" = %s LIMIT 21' 
- PARAMS = (u'1',)

# to_edit.save():
QUERY = u'UPDATE "main_testmodel" SET "name" = %s, "key_id" = %s 
WHERE "main_testmodel"."id" = %s' 
- PARAMS = (u"'edited_test'", u'2', u'1')

# to_update = TestModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(name='updated_name', key=new_key):
QUERY = u'UPDATE "main_testmodel" SET "name" = %s, "key_id" = %s 
WHERE "main_testmodel"."id" = %s' 
- PARAMS = (u"'updated_name'", u'3', u'2')
```

We have just one query for `update()` and two for `save()`.

Next, lets talk about overriding `save()` method. It is called only once for `save()` method obviously. It is worth mentioning, that `.objects.create()` also calls `save()` method.

But `update()` does not call `save()` on models. And if no `save()` method is called for `update()`, so the signals are not triggered either. Output:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

# TestModel.objects.get(id=1):
Manager is called [<TestModel: edited_test new_for 0>]
Manager is called [<TestModel: edited_test new_for 0>]
save() is called.
signal dispatched
signal dispatched

# to_update = TestModel.objects.filter(id=2).update(name='updated_name', key=new_key):
Manager is called [<TestModel: edited_test new_for 0>]
```

As you can see `save()` triggers `Manager`'s `get_queryset()` twice. When `update()` only once.

Resolution. If you need to "silently" update your values, without `save()` been called - use `update`. Usecases: `last_seen` user's field. When you need to update your model properly use `save()`.

Comment: Another key difference is, when you use "auto_now" or "auto_now_add" attr in DataField or DateTimeField, The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). the field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Answer (score 50):

Both looks similar, but there are some key points:

1. `save()` will trigger any overridden `Model.save()` method, but `update()` will not trigger this and make a direct update on the database level. So if you have some models with overridden save methods, you must either avoid using update or find another way to do whatever you are doing on that overridden `save()` methods.
2. `obj.save()` may have some side effects if you are not careful. You retrieve the object with `get(...)`  and all model field values are passed to your obj. When you call `obj.save()`, django will save the current object state to record. So if some changes happens between `get()` and `save()` by some other process, then those changes will be lost. use `save(update_fields=[.....])` for avoiding such problems.
3. Before Django version 1.5, Django was executing a `SELECT` before `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, so it costs 2 query execution. With version 1.5, that method is deprecated.

[In here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save), there is a good guide or `save()` and `update()` methods and how they are executed.

Comment: so for the second one, it's better to use `obj.refresh_from_db()` before triggering `obj.save()`

Comment: @AvinashRaj there still is a risk though between those 2 line for the db data to change. But it is reduced now.

Comment: or  `obj.save(['value'])` i.e. a list of your values

Answer (score 13):

save() method can be used to insert new record and update existing record and generally used for saving instance of single record(row in mysql) in database.

update() is not used to insert records and can be used to update multiple records(rows in mysql) in database.

Answer (score 12):

Using update directly is more **efficient** and could also prevent **integrity** problems.

**From the official documentation** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update

> If you’re just updating a record and don’t need to do anything with
> the model object, the most efficient approach is to call update(),
> rather than loading the model object into memory. For example, instead
> of doing this:
>
> ```
> e = Entry.objects.get(id=10)
> e.comments_on = False
> e.save()
> ```
>
> …do this:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.filter(id=10).update(comments_on=False)
> ```
>
> Using update() also prevents a race condition wherein something might
> change in your database in the short period of time between loading
> the object and calling save().

Answer (score 6):

Update only works on updating querysets. If you want to update multiple fields at the same time, say from a dict for a single object instance you can do something like:

```
obj.__dict__.update(your_dict)
obj.save()
```

Bear in mind that your dictionary will have to contain the correct mapping where the keys need to be your field names and the values the values you want to insert.

Answer (score 4):

Update will give you better performance with a queryset of more than one object, as it will make one database call per queryset.

However save is useful, as it is easy to override the save method in your model and add extra logic there. In my own application for example, I update a dates when other fields are changed.

```
Class myModel(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField()
    date_created = models.DateField()

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk :
           ### we have a newly created object, as the db id is not set
           self.date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(myModel , self).save()
```

Comment: why to use `if not self.pk :` and set  `self.date_created` rather using `auto_now=True` in the decalaration of  `date_created` field

Comment: true @SanthoshYedidi but i think, it is just example of how you can override `save` method

Answer (score 2):

**`save()`**:

- can be used with **model object** but not with **`QuerySet` or `Manager` objects**.
- with **`select_for_update()`** can run **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query**.

**`update()`**

- can be used with **`QuerySet` or `Manager` objects** but not with **model object**.
- with **`select_for_update()`** cannot run **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query**.

For example, I have **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, you can use **`save()`** with **`Person` model object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, you cannot use **`save()`** with **`QuerySet` object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.filter(pk=1)
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

And, you cannot use **`save()`** with **`Manager` object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'save'

Then, you can use **`update()`** with **`QuerySet` object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.filter(pk=1)
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

And, you can use **`update()`** with **`Manager` object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, you cannot use **`update()`** with **`Person` model object** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.filter(pk=1).first()    
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'update'

Next for example, **`select_for_update()`** is used to prevent **race condition(lost update or write skew)** when updating data in Django.

And, I have **`test` view** with **`save()`** and **`select_for_update().filter(pk=1).first()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=1).first() # Here
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below. *I used **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the query logs of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log SQL queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

Now, I remove **`first()`** to use **`update()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk=1) # Here
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** is not run and only **`UPDATE` query** is run as shown below:

[image]

And, I have **`test` view** with **`save()`** and **`select_for_update().get(pk=1)`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=1) # Here
    person.name = 'Tom'
    person.save() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` queries** are run as shown below:

[image]

Now, I remove **`get()`** to use **`update()`** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    person = Person.objects.select_for_update() # Here
    person.update(name="Tom") # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, when I run **`test` view**, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** is not run and only **`UPDATE` query** is run as shown below:

[image]

So, **`save()`** with **`select_for_update()`** can run **`SELECT FOR UPDATE` query** while **`update()`** with **`select_for_update()`** cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Use _state.adding to differentiate update from create https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Check how the current values differ from ._loaded_values. For example,
    # prevent changing the creator_id of the model. (This example doesn't
    # support cases where 'creator_id' is deferred).
    if not self._state.adding and (
            self.creator_id != self._loaded_values['creator_id']):
        raise ValueError("Updating the value of creator isn't allowed")
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the differences that might cause a lot of headaches is that `save` updates, but `update` does NOT update columns of type `DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`
or `ModificationDateTimeField`
These fields automatically (should) set their date when an object is saved to the database.