# Set component style from variable in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

My goal is to set a style (height and width in this case) from a component variable using the "styles" attribute. I would think there is a simple data binding method but that may be wishful thinking...

For example if I were using the html mustache binding it might look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[sidebar]',
    templateUrl: 'app/Nav/sidebar.comp.html',
    styles: [`
        .sidebar-nav {
            overflow: scroll;
            height: {{ height }};
        }
        .sidebar {
            height: {{ 0.9 * height }};
            width: {{ 0.21 * width }};
        }
    `]
})

export class SidebarComp {
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor() {
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
}
```

Obviously this is all wrong but I've tried some more likely permutations and had no luck finding solutions on the Angular site, Stack Overflow, or Google. I may be reduced to using ngStyle inline but that's not ideal in this case.

Comment: You don't show what you want to style. Is `.sidebar` the `SidebarComp` itself or something inside `sidebar.comp.html`?

Answer (score 27):

You can style the host element like

```
@Component({
  selector: '[sidebar]',
  templateUrl: 'app/Nav/sidebar.comp.html',
  host: {
    '[style.height.px]':'0.9 * height',
    '[style.width.px]':'0.21 * width'
  }

})

export class SidebarComp {
    width: number;
    height: number;

    constructor() {
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
    }
}
```

and the content (`app/Nav/sidebar.comp.html`) like

```
<div class="sidebar-nav" [style.overflow]="'scroll'" [style.height.px]="height">
```

or

```
<div class="sidebar-nav" [ngStyle]="{overflow: 'scroll', height: height + 'px'}">
```

Comment: And in PsudoClass?

Comment: @AlejoNext sorry, no idea what you mean

Comment: `::before` how edit the style? in typescript or javascript

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not supported

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer where did you find the documention for this?

Comment: What part? . . . .

Answer (score 4):

If you are using percent (%) try this :

```
<div class="sidebar-nav"   [style.height.%]="height">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need change image style dynamic switch between px and % unit.

So I use `[ngStyle]` instead of `[style.height.px]`

I share for whom concern.

HTML

```
<img [src]="imageUrl | safe: 'url'" [ngStyle]="{width: imagewidth, height: imageheight}">
```

TS

```
    if (this.properties.imageStyle == 'Stretch') {
      this.imagewidth = this.cols * this.unitWidth + 'px';
      this.imageheight = this.rows * this.unitHeight + 'px';
    }

    if (this.properties.imageStyle == 'Clip') {
      this.imagewidth = 100 + '%';
      this.imageheight = 100 + '%';
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-clip-stretch