# not set property value on div with javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to set these properties when click on the div in angular with javascript:

```
maximunWidth() {
    var parentDiv = document.querySelector(".cadr");
    parentDiv.setAttribute("width",(this.size.width - 2).toString());
    parentDiv.setAttribute("height",(this.size.height - 41).toString());
}
```

and this is my html code :

```
<div id="cadr" class="cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

What's the problem? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Did you try `ng-click="maximunWidth()"` in your HTML (if you're using angularjs v1.x)?

Comment: i using the `click` . angular version 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set component style from variable in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130705/set-component-style-from-variable-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not **recommended** to change the dom element directly you can use `ngStyle`
 directive

*template*

```
<div id="cadr" class="cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6" 
     [ngStyle]="{'width.px':width ,'height.px':height  }"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

*component*

```
public width = 'initial'; //  default value 
public height  = 'initial'; //  default value 

public maximunWidth() { 
 this.width = this.size.width - 2;
 this.height = this.size.height - 41;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid accessing the html elements directly. The whole point of Angular is (very much simplified) to take care of the DOM for you.

Instead of setting attributes directly let Angular take care of this for you:

```
<div id="cadr" class="cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6"
     [ngStyle]="{'width': calculatedWidth, 'height': calculatedHeight}"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

And populate these values with the computed values in your typescript:

```
maximunWidth() {
    this.calculatedWidth = ...;
    this.calculatedHeight = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="cadr" class="cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6"  [style.width]="widthDiv+'%'" [style.height]="heightDiv+'%'"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

or,

```
<div id="cadr" class="cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6"  [style.width]="widthDiv+'px'" [style.height]="heightDiv+'px'"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

## .ts

```
public maximunWidth() { 
 this.widthDiv= this.size.width - 2;
 this.heightDiv= this.size.height - 41;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your way of implementation whenever you click it will decrease the dimesion of that `div` tag. Try using property binding.

```
cssClass = 'oldSize'
maximunWidth() {
    this.cssClass = 'newSize'
}
```

In your html

```
<div id="cadr" [class]=" 'cadr ' + 'col-md-6 ' + 'col-xl-6 ' + 'col-sm-12 ' + 'col-lg-6 ' + cssClass"></div>
<div class="minmize" (click)="maximunWidth()"></div>
```

Comment: there is a small error `'cadr'  'col-md-6'` => `'cadr'  + 'col-md-6' ...` 

Comment: I think it 's better to use `[ngClass ] ="{'cadr col-md-6 col-xl-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6' : true ,newSize : toggleState , oldSize : !toggleState"` I just like to use ngStle and ngClass 