# Possibility of having variable parameter names in Django model updates

Tags: python, django, model

I'd like to shorten the following code from

```
if field == 'favorite_food':
    model_instance.update(favorite_food=value)
elif field == 'favorite_drink':
    model_instance.update(favorite_drink=value)
elif field == 'favorite_color':
    model_instance.update(favorite_color=value)
```

to something like:

```
if field in list:    
    model_instance.update(field=value)
```

So I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: yes you can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [*unpack into keyword arguments*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
model_instance.update(**{field: value})
```

---

There is also an option to set the model field value and then save (there are though [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449960/django-save-vs-update-to-update-the-database)):

```
setattr(model_instance, field, value)
model_instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
fields = ["favorite_food", "favorite_drink", "favorite_color"]
field = "favorite_food"
if field in fields:    
    model_instance.update(field=value)
```