# question about save(update_fields) method nuances , Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Quick question. Cant find it in documentation or rather there are contradictory information.

Does method:

```py
save(update_fields = somefields)
```

works by the same principal as method:

```py
SomeModel.objects.update(somefields here)
```

in terms that both methods work on the DB level without triggering SAVE method in the model?

UPDATE works on a DB level, that's clear

What about save(update_fields = somefields)???

Thank you and sorry for rather abstract question

```py
    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        self.show = False
        self.change_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.save(update_fields=["show", "change_date"]) # will it trigger save() method in the model or not???
```

Comment: Maybe this help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Comment: Especially note what happens when the instance was fetched with any deferred fields.  `Model.save` does some sort of tricky things which are useful but less obvious than `Manager.update`.  While not entirely the same question, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30453181/2715819) has a lot of useful info.

Comment: Calling `save` method does trigger the method `save`. And `update_fields` argument is passed to the `pre_save` and `post_save` signals. Any way you call `save` it ends up in `save_base`. `self.save(...) ... will it trigger save() method in the model` **it is** the code triggering `save` method, isn't it?

Comment: in django docs it says : "Specifying update_fields will force an update". This is not clear.. will it use Manager.update() in this case or it is just standard save() but with a limited set of the fields?. Thing is that datetimefield with auto_add doesnt work with save(update_fields). I just thought that it becouse update_fields works on DB level and in this case there are no signals that might triget auto_add somehow. Just a guess

Comment: That is in terms of whether _an update or insert must happen_ in the end. There is a `force_update` option. However when `update_fields` is passed - _an update will be forced already_.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py `if force_insert and (force_update or update_fields):
            raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.")`

Comment: ok, more or less clear now. Thank you all

Comment: pre_save should trigger pre-save() method and later used by auto_now ...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save,then any type of save() should work correctly with auto_add, hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using save(update_fields=[.....]) forces an update query in the db level, it is slower than the update() method because an extra call to super.save() is made before that.

`super.save(*args, **kwargs)`

Instead of using save with update_fields, try using something similar to this.

`YourModel.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(show=False, change_date=datetime.datetime.now())`